# open PDF in browser with PHP

Tags: php, html, pdf

I am doing:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="the.pdf"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
@readfile($file);
```

and it works fine. The PDF opens in the browser.

Can I do an if-then-else before? I tried and I get raw PDF

```
%PDF-1.2 9 0 obj << /Type/Font /Subtype/Type1 /Name/F1 /FontDescriptor 8 0
```

Why is the if-then-else changing the headers?

thanks.

Comment: Can you give some example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful if you posted exactly what is your if-then-else code. My guess is you have some whitespace output before the headers are outputted.

Comment: You were right. Whitespace before <?php. Works fine now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the code in your if-then-else block isn't causing anything to be output to the page.

Once something's been output, calls to `header()` won't work anymore.