# Open PDF in browser that is stored outside the webroot

Tags: php, pdf

I have some PDF's that are only accessible to members only (they have to log in to get them). I'd like to have them show up in the browser, instead a dialog box is showing up asking to save/open the file. The PDF's are stored outside of the regular root directory. Here's the code:

```
$filepath='/var/www/vhosts/Reports/';
$filename='CA.pdf';
header('Content-Disposition:inline; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Content-type:application/octet-stream');
header('Pragma:no-cache');
header('Expires:0');
if ($file=fopen($filepath.$filename,'r')) {
fpassthru($file);
fclose($file);
```

I read that setting the disposition to inline should fix it, but no good. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to just comment on your post but I am a noob to overflow. I just wanted to share some google search results. Have you tried @readfile?

[Show a PDF files in users browser via PHP/Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679756/show-a-pdf-files-in-users-browser-via-php-perl)

[open PDF in browser with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750252/open-pdf-in-browser-with-php)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The content type should be 'application/pdf', a browser will recognise this as a pdf and open it as such.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = "../../somewherebehindthatroot/FileName.pdf";

if ( file_exists($file) ) {     
    
    if (copy($file, "OpenThisFile.pdf")) { echo "<br /><br /><a href='OpenThisFile.pdf'  target='_blank'>Open File...</a>"; }
            
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a description for the code? It is a good practice to add description so the readers seeking for help can easily understand what have you done here.